# Dismiss the Keyguard without unlock sound

Tags: android

I am writing a replacement LockScreen, and using `LayoutParams.DISSMISS_KEYGUARD` as a Window flag is dismissing the Keyguard when switching on the screen and launching my LockScreen, however it always plays an lock sound when pressing the power button again, how can I surpress the lock sound?

Answer (score 1):

you could use an `AudioManager` to turn the sound off in `OnCreate` then turn it back on later. You would also want to check if the sound is off to start so that you don't turn the sound on when it was off already

This to check sound state

```
am = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
switch (am.getRingerMode()) {
case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT:
case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE:
    silentMode = true;
    break;
case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL:
    silentMode = false;
    break;
}
```

This to turn sound off

```
am = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
am.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE);
    OR
am.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
```

This to turn sound on

```
am = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
am.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
```

Of course you would probably make `am` a private variable so you don't need to declare it more than once. Like this.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    //more variables
    private AudioManager am;
    private boolean silentMode;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        am = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        //check sound state and set silentMode;
        //more stuff
    }
}
```

I don't really know when to turn the sound back on but a place to try maybe after the call to `getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);`

Comment: Thanks, I will try it out, but I guess this might be race condition, because the KeyGuard is Dismissed also in onCreate.

Comment: Yeah I just realized that turning the sound back on also plays a sound . This will only work if you want your lock screen to be silent. Then turn the sound back on when you unlock the screen.